# How to fix error during build of next js and Mui?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I have installed `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/server` and have tried to build next js app and received an error during linting and checking

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@mui/base/useMenu/useMenu.d.ts:3:15
Type error: ',' expected.

  1 | import { MenuItemMetadata, UseMenuListboxSlotProps, UseMenuParameters } from './useMenu.types';
  2 | import { EventHandlers } from '../utils';
> 3 | import { type MenuUnstyledContextType } from '../MenuUnstyled';
    |               ^
  4 | /**
  5 |  *
```

Thanks for your help.

EsLint config

```
    {
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "object-curly-newline": [
      "error",
      {
        "ObjectExpression": {
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured our how to fix my project problem and possibly that will help others as well. I have typescript version 4.4.9 I changed to 4.5.2 and linting passed correctly

Comment: I had the same issue, and this solution did the trick.